# String output query

Tags: c#, string

I am new to this comunity and I am seeking advise on how to improve my current script. Below is the code:

```
if (condition1 == true) string stringname  = "dog";
if (condition2 == true) string stringname1 = "cat";
if (condition3 == true) string stringname2 = "mouse";
if (condition4 == true) string stringname3 = "crab";

Format.String("Animal Type: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", stringname, stringname1, stringname2, stringname3); // print to output
```

Specifically what I would like is to be able to display the result in the output window in the following way:

example 1:
assuming condition 1 and 3 are true and 2 and 4 are false: "Animal Type: dog, mouse"
Whilst with my current script I would get: "Animal Type: dog,, mouse,"

example 2:
assuming condition 2 and 3 are true: "Animal Type: cat, mouse"
Whilst with my current script I would get: "Animal Type: ,cat, mouse,"

Answer (score 3):

```
var animals = new List<string>();
if (condition1) animals.Add("dog");
if (condition2) animals.Add("cat");
if (condition3) animals.Add("mouse");
if (condition4) animals.Add("crab");
string result = "Animal Type: " + string.Join(", ", animals);
```

Comment: this really helped thanks!

what if I know that the output can be only 1 of the names in the list, how should I adjust my result field? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to join the strings, I would look at using

[String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)

> Concatenates the members of a constructed IEnumerable(Of T) collection
>   of type String, using the specified separator between each member.

So you can try something like

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
if (condition1) vals.Add("dog");
if (condition2) vals.Add("cat");
if (condition3) vals.Add("mouse");
if (condition4) vals.Add("crab");
```

And then try something like

```
Format.String("Animal Type: {0}, String.Join(",", vals));
```

Comment: this really helped thanks!

what if I know that the output can be only 1 of the names in the list, how should I adjust my result field? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The closest direct match would be something along the lines of:

```
console.WriteLine(string.Format("Animal Type: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", (condition1 ? "dog", ""), (condition2 ? "cat", ""), (condition3 ? "mouse", ""), (condition4 ? "crab", ""))); // print to output
```

With your code you're declaring the variable only for the scope of the `if`.

Another approach would be to push them into a list, for example, something like:

```
var selected = new List<string>();
if (condition1 == true) selected.Add("dog");
if (condition2 == true) selected.Add("cat");
if (condition3 == true) selected.Add("mouse");
if (condition4 == true) selected.Add("crab");

console.WriteLine(string.Format("Animal Type: {0}", string.Join(", ", selected.ToArray()))); // print to output
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it with a HashSet like this

```
 var animals = new HashSet<string>();
 if (condition1) animals.Add("dog");
 if (condition2) animals.Add("cat");
 if (condition3) animals.Add("mouse");
 if (condition4) animals.Add("crab");
 string result = "Animal Type: " + string.Join(", ", animals);
```

Comment: this really helped thanks!

what if I know that the output can be only 1 of the names in the list, how should I adjust my result field? thanks

Comment: example of your input and output you expect?

Comment: var animals = new HashSet<string>();
 if (condition1) animals.Add("dog");
 if (condition2) animals.Add("cat");
 if (condition3) animals.Add("mouse");
 if (condition4) animals.Add("crab");
 string result = "only 1 of the above conditions, e.i. mouse"

assumption is that only 1 of the 4 conditions above can be true

Comment: even in that case the above answer is correcy. You will get a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string output = "Animal Type: ";
            if (condition1 == true) output  += "dog ,";
            if (condition2 == true) output += "cat ,";
            if (condition3 == true) output += "mouse ,";
            if (condition4 == true) output += "crab ,";

            output = output.Substring(0, output.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, defining a list of strings and putting in your values if true would be the solution.
After that, Join it with semicolon as delimiter.

```
List<string> outList = new List<string>();
if (true) outList.Add("dog");
if (false) outList.Add("cat");
if (true) outList.Add("mouse");
if (false) outList.Add("crab");
Console.Write(String.Format("Animal Type: {0}", String.Join(",", outList)));
```